# Template specialization with variadic non-type arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to detect if a type is of type A (with any template parameters). I'm using a helper struct and template specialization for it. I did the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename,typename,typename,typename,int... pars> struct A{};

template<typename T> struct check: std::false_type{} ;

template<typename... T>
struct check<A<T...>> : std::true_type{}; // specialization is not applied

template<typename... T, int... pars>
struct check<A<T...,pars...>> : std::true_type{}; // same

// the following would get applied for any A:

// template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, int... pars> 
// struct check<A<T1,T2,T3,T4,pars...>> : std::true_type{};

int main(){
    std::cout << check<A<int,char,double,int,1,2,3>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However, it will print out 0, so the uncommented specializations are not applied. Is it not supposed to work or am I missing something here? Is there a similar or alternative way of detecting for any type A, without having to write out all the `typename T1` etc for the class A as in the commented line above?

Comment: Note: clang won't compile this: https://godbolt.org/z/Eg6cG2 "error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization"

Answer (score 0):

Even though our human brains can deduce a parameter pack of types next to a parameter pack of non-types, the compiler is not willing to try to figure out where one parameter pack ends, and another begins.

In general, there's just not a good way to mix a variable number of type and non-type arguments. The general workaround is, if you can modify `A`, to promote the non-type arguments to types:

```cpp
template <int... pars>
using make_pars = std::integer_sequence<int, pars...>;
```

And then, the check is much simpler

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct check : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct check<A<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

And there's not much extra boilerplate when using:

```cpp
std::cout << check<A<int,char,double,int,make_pars<1,2,3>>>::value << std::endl;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7pMp2e

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had seen some examples of a specialization using multiple variadic packs, like this https://godbolt.org/z/2zfpf-. However, if it has to expand the variadic parameters right next to each other, it is indeed not willing to figure it out.